# AJAX In Cart Page Returning Odd HTML Instead Of Data Object

Tags: add-on-development, ajax, shopping-cart, json, addons

EE 5.2.6

This is a very strange problem.

I have a class that I'm using to query the Amazon Product Advertising API and return data via AJAX.

I have category pages and product pages where the jQuery and PHP class are working just perfectly, meaning a user is able to click a button and the class processes data through the Amazon API (to update cart) and returns data that changes values on the frontend.

- click 'add to cart'
- ajax call runs php function (using ACTion id) that sets up and modifies a cart on Amazon
- json is returned pertaining to elements that need to be changed on the frontend

This is all working perfectly *EXCEPT* when you get to the cart page.

On the cart page the cart items are showing just fine, but when you attempt to modify or remove an item from the cart ON THIS PAGE ONLY, instead of processing the data and returning a json object, it is not even reaching the class and is returning html with some random table.

This code and these templates are something I copied over almost exactly from a production server, and on that site everything is working perfectly. No problems at all.

Do you have any idea why I'm getting some strange html with a table in it instead of running the class methods that my add-on is supposed to run (and does run on another site)?

I feel like it has something to do with EE but I'm not sure and wanted to check with the fine community here before trying to debug it further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue with EE. I have since fixed the problem which had to do with action URL and SSL.